# The cookie '.AspNetCore.Identity.Application' has set 'SameSite=None' and must also set 'Secure'

Tags: asp.net-core, identity

I followed these links:

- [Prepare your identity server](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/identity/samesite/prepare-your-identityserver/)
- [How to delete samesies cookies](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/identity/samesite/how-to-delete-samesite-cookies/)

These are my settings:

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

services.ConfigureNonBreakingSameSiteCookies();

// Adjust to this (or similar)
services
    .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
     {
        // add an instance of the patched manager to the options:
        options.CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager();
      });
```

And then in the configure:

```cs
app.UseCookiePolicy();
```

I am trying to run identity over http. I get those errors when setting certain (but not all) cookies, and I completely fail to delete the cookies in chrome

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything is okay in your code, but you should more configure your cookies.

Add additional attributes - `Secure`, `HttpOnly` and `SameSite` in `AddCookie`. More information in [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-5.0#net-core-support-for-the-samesite-attribute)

Example:

```
        services
           .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddCookie(options =>
           {
               // add an instance of the patched manager to the options:
               options.CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager();

                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
           });
```

Answer (score 11):

In case anyone else comes across this and still has a problem.  I ended up having to do a similar change for the NonceCookie and CorrelationCookie properties to get them to work.  Our system is using Identity Server and lives behind a Load Balancer that also offloads the SSL piece.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
   options.DefaultScheme = "cookies";
   options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("cookies", options =>
{
   options.Cookie.Name = "appcookie";
   options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
   options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
})
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
   options.NonceCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
   options.CorrelationCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
...
}
```

Comment: SameSiteMode.Strict works for you? doesn't it have to be None for identity server to be able to set it on the client?

Comment: @GuyLevy oddly enough it is working with SameSiteMode set to Strict.  I had expected it to fail with that setting but it hasn't.

Comment: this doesn´t work for me in Chrome for .NET 7 and latest Identity Server packages as per today . Firefox doesn´t have that problem.
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect 7.0.0` and `Duende.IdentityServer 6.1.7`

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late for the party. However, this is my solution. The following code was added to the `ConfigureServices` method.

[image]

```
services.Configure<AntiforgeryOptions>(config =>
        {
            config.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        });

        services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>(config =>
        {
            config.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = _env.IsDevelopment() ? CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest : CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
        });
```