# Asp.NetCore Identity and Google Authentication Not working behind Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nginx

I have an Asp.Net Core MVC 7 application. A simple crud app for the family. I enabled Google authentication and everything works fine on local host. I deployed to a linux vm with nginx as my reverse proxy and letsencrypt ssl setup. The app is at a subdomain for example myapp.mydomain.com. When I try to sign in with google, it just throws an exception with the error

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1](https://andrewlock.net/supporting-legacy-browsers-and-samesite-cookies-without-useragent-sniffing-in-aspnetcore/)
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
> ---> System.Exception: OAuth token endpoint failure: invalid_client;Description=Unauthorized
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

I am running the site in developer mode to see the error. I have setup oauth access with google as per the microsoft learn docs. so my redirect uri is https://myapp.mydomain.com/signin-google. Below are the configuration and settings for the app:

```
server {

    server_name myapp.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:6003;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    # returns 404 for static files unless this is here
    location ~* /(css|js|lib|ico) {
        root /var/www/html/fruglapp/wwwroot;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = myapp.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name myapp.mydomain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I configured my app with settings from Andrew locks article here : [SameSite issue](https://andrewlock.net/supporting-legacy-browsers-and-samesite-cookies-without-useragent-sniffing-in-aspnetcore/)
Here is the configuration in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => 
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(
    IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
    scheme => scheme.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None
);
builder.Services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(
    IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
    scheme => scheme.CookieManager = new CookieManagerWrapper()
);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie(x =>
    {
        x.CookieManager = new CookieManagerWrapper();
        x.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        x.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        x.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    })
    .AddGoogle(opt => {
        opt.ClientId = builder.Configuration["CLIENT_ID"]!;
        opt.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["CLIENT_SECRET"]!;
    });
```

Can anyone see something I have done wrong? Or does anyone have an idea of what is going on? Been on this for 2 days and I have toggled different settings and still haven't been able to solve this. Just for context, I have looked at these answer on stackoverflow: [SameSite=None issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66545492/the-cookie-aspnetcore-identity-application-has-set-samesite-none-and-must-a)

Comment: Check the app settings in your Google Dev Console, you may need to add additional URLs here.

Comment: Will check again and see.

Comment: I added the address the mvc app is running on (127.0.0.1:6003)/signin-google. Nothing changed. @DisplayName can you elaborate on your comment? I don't see what url I should be adding other than these 2

Comment: Not super familiar with nginx syntax but if 6003 is the port your app is running on, that's not the port that Google will see, as they will be communicating through your proxy. Also the URL should be the external one - try variations on myapp.mydomain.com:80.

Comment: @DisplayName I don't know but I can try it. I have been digging into the docs at microsoft. I have been getting help and guidance from the great Andrew Lock also so I will post a solution when I find one.

Comment: so I found out why from the microsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-7.0#forward-request-information-with-a-proxy-or-load-balancer. But setting the scheme so things remain https might be the issue. Tried setting `context.Request.Scheme = "https";` and setting the hostname to the domain I used  but still nada.